# Ruby Dir.glob output without file extensions

Tags: ruby

`Dir.glob("*.txt")` gives all filles that have the txt file extension. I want the `.txt` extension not to get printet. What could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map over the results of `Dir.glob` and use `File.basename` to remove the extension. Like this: `Dir.glob("*.txt").map {|f| File.basename(f, ".*")}`